# Cell contains number+text, conditional format based on number greater than

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Cell will hold 0TRUE/ 1FALSE/ 3FALSE/ (number)(true/false)

If cell contains TRUE and number is greater than 3, conditional format cell fill colour

I want to get the numeric part by subtracting a date column from today. If it's more than 3, the rule would apply. Could you please help with a formula for date subtraction?

[image]

Comment: Share a sample google-sheet file. In you example, all data in one cell?

Comment: Please elaborate your concern, in addition to what @Harun24hr said, share your input and expected results as well.

Comment: can you please share a copy of your sheet with examples and your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this Conditional Formatting rule and see if it performs as requested.  (Note that I have applied the Conditional Formatting to M1:M in the sample screenshot below.

> =AND(REGEXMATCH(M1,"([4-9]|[1-9]\d+)"),REGEXMATCH(M1,"(?i)TRUE"))

The first `REGEXMATCH` checks for numbers between 4 and 9 or double digit numbers greater than 9.  The second `REGEXMATCH` checks for the string "TRUE".  The **(?i)** before the **TRUE** makes it case-insensitive.  If case-sensitivity matters, it can be removed.  By wrapping these `REGEXMATCHES` in the `AND` function, both conditions must be met for the cell to be highlighted.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I want to get the numeric part by subtracting a date column from today. If it's more than 3, the rule you suggested would apply. Could you please help with a formula for date subtraction? I have attached an image to the original post

Comment: It would be better to start a new post for this second question, as it changes the nature of the original question.  Feel free to copy the link of the new post to this comment section and I  can take a look.